# 2sxc : How to get list of all application Content-Types

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Is there any public methode in [2sxc](http://2sxc.org/en/) for get all Content-Types?

Or how to get list of all content-types?

(edit / added)

When I get all appTypes (from my answer below) i can access all Fields by this code:

```
var fieldList = (myType as ToSic.Eav.Data.ContentType).AttributeDefinitions;
```

the result is Dictionary of AttributeBase with properties: Name, Type, IsTitle, SortOrder,...

But I don't find properties for : REQUIRED, Visible In Edit UI, RowCount,...

Where or how I can access this properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this code and work OK

```
  var cache = ToSic.Eav.DataSource.GetCache(null, App.AppId) as ToSic.Eav.DataSources.Caches.BaseCache;
  var allTypes = cache.GetContentTypes().Select(t => t.Value);
  var appTypes = allTypes.Where(t => t.Scope == "2SexyContent").ToList();
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: I edit and extend original question with accessing Content-Type Fields properties